# my wp schedule event is not working

Tags: wp-cron

```
function wp_cron_define(){

    add_filter('cron_schedules', function($schedules){
        $schedules['mine'] = array(
            'interval' => 30,
            'display' => 'once in a week'
         ); //for defining the schedule timing 

        if(!wp_next_scheduled('sen_hook')) {

            wp_schedule_event( time(),'mine','sen_hook');

        }

}

add_action('sen_hook','hello');

function hello(){
    echo 'hello';
}

add_action('wp','wp_cron_define');
```

now whenever the user visit the page they should see the hello but i am not seeing any thing so a little help from dev would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WP cron tasks execute in completely separate process from page load. Nothing from the task's output will be ever seen by users. That's the *purpose* of them, to run scheduled task without interfering with site itself.

If you want to output to the page periodically you will have to build it in other way. You could store the data (such as timestamps) in an option and compare/against it on load.

Comment: i tried to send email through this cron if the work is not executed how to know the error?

Comment: Personally I use `error_log` function to log diagnostic messages from my cron job.

Comment: My main problem was my function hello wasn't triggered so how could i debug so i just wanted to check whats wrong with it.